# Load different videos into mbox by text-links

Tags: hyperref, movie15

I integrated videos to my LaTeX document which worked perfectly:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
    \mbox{
        \movie[width=15.75cm, height=6cm, showcontrols=false, loop, poster, autostart]{}{animations/chap_04/Ani_04_01.mp4}
    }
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{Label}
\end{figure}
```

Now I would like to load different video files into the `\mbox`. To load each video I would like use text-links which are placed somewhere below the video frame. Is it possible? If it is, how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `movie15` shouldn't be used anymore.

The replacement, `media9`, is capable of doing exactly what you are after. The following example is taken from its manual. Any number of video files can be embedded using the `addresource` option. Videos are loaded by means of the `setSource` method which is bound to buttons below the video box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  label=some_dice,
  width=0.4\linewidth,height=0.3\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=random.mp4, %two video files
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  transparent,
  flashvars={
    source=random.mp4
   &loop=true             % loop video
   &scaleMode=letterbox   % preserve aspect ratio while scaling the video
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=some_dice:setSource [(random.mp4)]
]{\fbox{\strut random.mp4}}
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=some_dice:setSource [(cube.mp4)]
]{\fbox{\strut cube.mp4}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue with media9 package!

I tried it and unfortunately the buttons did work. The first video was loading, but the buttons didn't effect anything ... (I tried: Mac OS X 10.8 with Adobe Acrobat 11.0.0.2)

Comment: @Freddi: Did you run LaTeX twice, as the warning messages suggest? There is some Label<->Ref interaction between video box and buttons which requires LaTeX to be rerun, as usual.

Comment: I don't know ... but I just reopened LaTeX and tried it again and it worked perfectly ;) So, thank you very much!